# Python - Tkinter Label Output?

Tags: python, python-2.7, user-interface, tkinter

How would I take my entries from Tkinter, concatenate them, and display them in the Label below (next to 'Input Excepted: ')? I have only been able to display them input in the python console running behind the GUI. Is there a way my InputExcept variable can be shown in the Label widget?

```
from Tkinter import *

master = Tk()
master.geometry('200x90')
master.title('Input Test')

def UserName():
    usrE1 = usrE.get()
    usrN2 = usrN.get()
    InputExcept = usrE1 + " " + usrN2
    print InputExcept 

usrE = Entry(master, relief=SUNKEN)
usrE.pack()

usrN = Entry(master, relief=SUNKEN)
usrN.pack()

Btn1 = Button(text="Input", command=UserName)
Btn1.pack()

lbl = Label(text='Input Excepted: ')
lbl.pack()

master.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two main steps to do:

- You need to declare `usrE`, `usrE` and `lbl` as global variables inside your callback method.
- You need to use [`config()`](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/tkinter-widget-configuration.htm) method to update the text of `lbl`.

**Program:**

Here is the solution:

```
from Tkinter import *

master = Tk()
master.geometry('200x90')
master.title('Input Test')

def UserName():
    global usrE
    global usrN
    global lbl

    usrE1 = usrE.get()
    usrN2 = usrN.get()
    InputExcept = usrE1 + " " + usrN2
    print InputExcept 
    lbl.config(text='User expected:'+InputExcept)


usrE = Entry(master, relief=SUNKEN)
usrE.pack()

usrN = Entry(master, relief=SUNKEN)
usrN.pack()

Btn1 = Button(master, text="Input", command=UserName)
Btn1.pack()

lbl = Label(master)
lbl.pack()

master.mainloop()
```

**Demo:**

Running the program above will lead you to the expected result:

[image]

**Note:**

Do not forget to specify the parent widget (`master`) on which you draw the label and the button.